# Breaking up one question into 3 or 5 for generalizing

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions

While composing my question I actually find out there are several questions of them. They are all about architecture design and follow the same line. However one is about declaring interfaces, another about inheritance and a third about class inheritance. So it can be generalized tremendously.

Is it okay to post three/five questions in a minute or five?

Answer (score 7):

Though perhaps technically you could, I would advice against it.

Start off with your most important/burning question. It is very likely that any advice/answer you receive influences the other questions you have. So see your first question through for a while and then ask the other one. This doesn't have to be a process of weeks or days, but give it some time.